# Extending the proof of Maschke's Theorem from finite groups to algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, integration, projective-geometry, projective-modules

In the theory of representations of a finite group there is Maschke's Theorem that any finite-dimensional representation of a finite group $G$ can be decomposed into a direct sum of irreducible representations. The fundamental step of the proof is that if $W \subset V$ is a subrepresentation of $V$, that is $W$ is fixed by the action of all elements of $G$, then $V$ can be decomposed into the direct sum of $W$ and some $W^\prime$ which is also fixed by the action of $G$.  This is done by taking a projection $P$ of $V$ onto $W$, and then constructing a projection $P^\prime$ whose kernel will be $W^\prime$:

$$ P^\prime = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \rho(g) \circ P \circ \rho(g^{-1}) $$

where $\rho(g): V \rightarrow V$ is how $g \in G$ acts on $V$ in the representation, and the factors of the summand are composed as linear functions from $V$ to $V$.  The crux is that the sum is invariant upon substituting $g$ with $gh$ for any fixed $h \in G$. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem#Group-theoretic_2, Etingof, *Introduction to representation theory*, Th. 4.1)

We can extend the concept of representation first to modules acted upon by the group algebra $\mathbb{C}[G]$ and then to modules over arbitrary finite-dimensional algebras over $\mathbb{C}$.  The conclusion of Maschke's Theorem is proven for algebras using different means.

My hope is to extend the above proof technique to the general representation of algebras.  Or rather, to have someone else extend the above proof, perhaps as a thesis problem.  I can see the following issues:

1. Clearly, we want to replace the sum over the group by an integral over the algebra.  The algebra is topologically $\mathbb{C}^n$ and so is not compact, which interferes with integrating.  But the summand is invariant if $g$ is replaced by any scalar multiple $\alpha g$, so instead of integrating over the algebra $A$, we can integrate over $A^* = (A-\{0\})/\left< x \equiv \alpha x: x \in A, x \neq 0, \alpha \in \mathbb{C}, \alpha \neq 0 \right>$, which is topologically a projective space over $\mathbb{C}$ and should be compact.
2. Because $A$ is an algebra, there is no well-defined inverse of elements of $A$.  How can this be circumvented?
3. $A^*$ does not inherit the internal $+$ from $A$ because it is not invariant under the equivalence relation we quotient by.  But $A^*$ does inherit the internal $\times$ from $A$.  $A^*$ should be compact because $\mathbb{C}$ is locally compact and $A$ is finite-dimensional.  This should allow constructing a unique Haar-like measure on $A^*$ that is appropriately invariant relative to $\times$.  Because $A^*$ should be compact, the measure should be able to be normalized to $\mu(A^*) = 1$.  This eliminates the factor of ${|G|}^{-1}$ from the beginning of the definition of $P^\prime$.
4. Because the conclusion of Maschke's Theorem is known to require that the Jacobson radical of $A$ be trivial, that condition will be needed in this construction.
5. Ideally this can be extended from algebras over $\mathbb{C}$ to algebras over general fields $k$.  Presumably we require that $k$ be a topological field that is locally compact.  If $k$ has a nonzero characteristic $p$, there are likely to be further conditions. For representations of finite groups, we need $p \nmid |G|$. In a group algebra, $|G|$ becomes the dimension of the algebra, so presumably there is a requirement on $p$ and the dimension of $A$.

Of course, this would only prove what is already known.  But I think that the machinery that is needed to extend the proof would have wider application.

Comment: Related to point 5 of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883403/adjoin-indeterminates-to-a-field-making-it-algebraically-closed-and-locally-comp

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what your question is—this seems rather to be an attempt to request someone to take on or assign a thesis problem, which is not the usual use of MO.  For (3), I don't see why $A^*$ should be closed under $\times$ (which I assume is what you mean by "inherit the internal $\times$ from $A$").  For (4), when the Jacobson radical is trivial, aren't you just asking to re-prove one of the equivalent characterisations of [semisimplicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_algebra)?

Comment: Are you just asking for Lemma I.6.10 in Feit's "The representation theory of finite groups"? This is hardly a thesis problem.